# WPF - Editable combobox text overwritten by source on load

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have an editable combobox that also has an item source which is effectively used to prompt users with some standard entries for that box whilst giving them the freedom to enter custom entries if they wish. So, everything works fine accept when I bind to a property with a value (which is not one off the list) it sets the comboboxes text to the first item in the item source. Just to be clear, the following steps demonstrate the issue.

1. I open the View with a clean Model (all the properties are null/default values
2. I enter a custom value into the editable combobox
3. I save the Model
4. I close the View
5. I re-open the View with the previously saved Model
6. The custom value which I saved should be displayed in the editable combobox, however it is overwritten by the first value in the item source list

Note: The value in the Model property is not changed, this issue is purely visual.

So, how can I stop the itemsource overwriting custom entries?

Here is the combo box XAML:

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Contact_Types, Mode=OneTime, Source={StaticResource Resources}}" Text="{Binding Model.type, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
```